# sed - Commenting a line matching a specific string AND that is not already commented out

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following test file

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Using the following sed I can comment out the *BBB* line.

```
# sed -e '/BBB/s/^/#/g' -i file
```

I'd like to only comment out the line if it does not already has a # at the begining.

```
# sed -e '/^#/! /BBB/s/^/#/g' file

sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: `/'
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any lines with multiple `#`s this would work:

```
sed -e '/BBB/ s/^#*/#/' -i file
```

Note: you don't need /g since you are doing at most one substitution per line.

Comment: This will always edit the matching line to begin with a single #. So if it began with three `#`s after this command it will "clean" it to just start with one `#`.  To alleviate this problem if it is a problem, simply change the matching part accordingly (e.g. `sed -e '/^BBB/`...)

Comment: `sed '/^#BBB/'` you mean. But if BBB is somewhere in the middle it won't work. There is an option to write `sed '/^#/! {/BBB/ s/^/#/}'` which will work way better but my initial solution is way more simple as long as you know its limitation.

Comment: How to escape this if we are using above in java program?

Comment: Like this: `sed -e '/BBB/ s|^(//)*|//|' -i file`. Note that it only works for single-like comments, assumes that comment starts at the beginning of the line and will replace multiple _pairs_ of `//` with a single `//`.

Comment: is it possible to put BBB in a input variable?

Comment: You can but correctly passing variable to `sed` isn't that easy - search SO for how to do that right.

Answer (score 23):

Another solution with the `&` special character which references the whole matched portion of the pattern space. It's a bit simpler/cleaner than capturing and referencing a regexp group.

```bash
sed -i 's/^[^#]*BBB/#&/' file
```

Comment: didn't know about the `&` char. Awesome!

Answer (score 16):

I find this solution to work the best.

```
sed -i '/^[^#]/ s/\(^.*BBB.*$\)/#\ \1/' file
```

It doesn't matter how many "#" symbols there are, it will never add another one. If the pattern you're searching for does not include a "#" it will add it to the beginning of the line, and it will also add a trailing space.

If you don't want a trailing space

```
sed -i '/^[^#]/ s/\(^.*BBB.*$\)/#\1/' file
```

Comment: You may want to replace "!" with "^" but otherwise this is a better solution than the official answer

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the BBB is at the beginning of a line, I ended up using an even simpler expression:

```
sed -e '/^BBB/s/^/#/' -i file
```

One more note for the future me. Do not overlook the `-i`. Because this won't work: `sed -e "..." same_file > same_file`.

Answer (score 3):

If **BBB** is at the beginning of the line:

```
sed 's/^BBB/#&/' -i file
```

If **BBB** is in the middle of the line:

```
sed 's/^[^#]*BBB/#&/' -i file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed -i '/![^#]/ s/\(^.*BBB.*$\)/#\ \1/' file`

This doesn't work for me with the keyword `*.sudo`, no comments at all...

Ony the syntax below works:
`sed -e '/sudo/ s/^#*/#/' file`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need the exclamation sign (!) as the caret symbol already negates whatever is inside the square brackets and will ignore all hash symbol from your search. This example worked for me:

`sed -i '/[^#]/ s/\(^.*BBB.*$\)/#\ \1/' file`

Answer (score 1):

Comment all "BBB", if it's haven't comment yet.

```
sed -i '/BBB/s/^#\?/#/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd usually supply `sed` with `-i.bak` to backup the file prior to making changes to the original copy:

`sed -i.bak '/BBB/ s/^#*/#/' file`

This way when done, I have both `file` and `file.bak` and I can decide to delete `file.bak` only after I'm confident.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to comment out not only exact matches for 'BBB' but also lines that have 'BBB' somewhere in the middle, you can go with following solution:

```
sed -E '/^([^#].*)?BBB/  s/^/#/'
```

This won't change any strings that are already commented out.