# comment and uncomment a specific lines starting with spaces

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am just starting to use Linux and I need to comment / uncomment certain lines of a .yml file. I have searched through the documentation and here in SO through different posts as this one for example: [comment a line with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998763/sed-commenting-a-line-matching-a-specific-string-and-that-is-not-already-comme)

I needto comment lines 1 and 3 from here:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

and unccomment line 1 and 3 from here:

```
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  #hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

I have used these commands:

```
sudo sed -i '/output.elasticsearch/s/^/#/g' /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
sudo sed -i '/["localhost:9200"]/s/^/#/g' /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
sudo sed -i '/output.logstash/s/^#//g' /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
sudo sed -i '/["localhost:5044"]/s/^  #//g' /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
```

But whereas this work for the line 1 of each block it does not work for the line 3 whcih has spaces before the # symbol and I do not get how to change

Comment: Research what `[` `]` means inside a regex. I recommend learning about regexes with https://regexcrossword.com/

Comment: I have also triedo without the [] so something like ```sudo sed -i '/localhost:9200/s/^/#/g' /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml``` does not work neither

Comment: `does not work neither` a sample like `echo 'hosts: ["localhost:9200"]' | sed '/localhost:9200/s/^/#/g'` "works" for me in a way the line is outputted with a leading `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be acheived with three sed commands executed on an example "filebeat.yml" file

```
 sed -Ei '/^output.elasticsearch:$/,/^.*hosts: \["localhost:9200"\]$/{s/(^.*$)/#\1/}' filebeat.yml
```

The first command searches from a line beginning with and ending with "output.elasticsearch" to a line containing "hosts: ["localhost:9200"]" For that subset search, it searches for the complete line (^.*$) and then substitutes this line prefixed with a # (#\1)

```
 sed -Ei '/(^.*#hosts: \["localhost:5044"\]$)/{s/(^.*#)(.*$)/  \2/g}' filebeat.yml
```

The second command searches for the log stash hosts line and splits the found line into two sections, the first section being the start of the line to # and then the second being the rest of the line. We then substitute the line for the second section, creating a line without # but with 2 spaces added as required by yaml syntax.

```
sed -Ei '/(^#output.logstash:$)/{s/(^.*#)(.*$)/\2/g}' filebeat.yml
```

The third command follows the same logic as the second but this time doesn't retain any spaces

Comment: that worked! thanks for for not only sending the solution but also explaining it :)

Comment: Also I realized after uncommenting ```#hosts: ["localhost:5044"]``` it also deletes the 2 spaces before the line that needs to be there as it is a .yml file, how can I add 2 spaces to it?

Comment: Should be a case of just adding two spaces in front of the /2 in the second command, I have amended.

Comment: fitst of all, thanks for your time, I tried that but this add 2 spaces to both lines I would need 2 spaces just to the ```hosts: ["localhost:5044"]``` line, maybe I cand add somehow 2 spaces after?

Comment: OK, I've had to split the solution into three commands.

Comment: you are a star! thanks a lot for your time and your explanations any documentation / web to learn regex for beginners?

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
sed '
    /output\.elasticsearch/s/^/#/;
    /\["localhost:9200"\]/s/^[[:space:]]*/&#/;
    /output\.logstash/s/^#//;
    /\["localhost:5044"\]/s/^\([[:space:]]*\)#/\1/;
' <<EOF
output.elasticsearch:
   # Array of hosts to connect to.
   hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
#output.logstash:
   # The Logstash hosts
   #hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
EOF
```

outputs:

```
#output.elasticsearch:
   # Array of hosts to connect to.
   #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
output.logstash:
   # The Logstash hosts
   hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

`[` (and `.`) are special inside regex - escape them. To preserve the intentation I matched blanks with a `[[:space:]]*`. There's no point in applying `g` global flag, if it's going to be one substitution anyway.

And a neat oneliner, because why not:

```
sed -i '/output\.elasticsearch/s/^/#/; /\["localhost:9200"\]/s/^[[:space:]]*/&#/; /output\.logstash/s/^#//; /\["localhost:5044"\]/s/^\([[:space:]]*\)#/\1/;' file_path
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation I just do not get where I set the file path within that code

Comment: `sed -i 'the script the script the script' the_file_path`. See `man sed` (of GNU sed, `-i` is supported on GNU implementation of `sed`), [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Overview) and various introductions to shell programming available on the net. Commands in sed are separated by newline and can be sometimes separated by `;`. You may do a oneliner.